# PHP namespace containing word "Case"

Tags: php, namespaces

When setting a namespace to "App\Case" I'm being thrown the following error:

```
syntax error, unexpected 'Case' (T_CASE), expecting identifier (T_STRING)
```

Code line in reference:

```
use App\Case;
```

Changing the word from "case" to something else fixes this. But from what I understand this is a valid namespace name and should not collide with the [reserved keyword](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.keywords.php) 'case' in PHP.

I encountered this issue whilst using Laravel migrations on Homestead CLI, but I don't believe this is relevant to the problem

Is this a bug or an invalid name in the namespace?

Comment: Invalid in the namespace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're reserved for a reason because in the first scenario above, PHP wouldn't be able to tell the difference between you defining an array or initialising a class of the same name, so it throws an error. There's no way round this like in MySQL, for example, where you can escape reserved words with a backtick. So in PHP you're forced to change the name, you don't have to change it much, one char will do as long as you're not using the exact same name as a reserved word.

Comment: PHP documentation on reserved words:
http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.keywords.php